# How to show PHP variable in HTML

Tags: php, html, variables, authentication

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// Initialize wrong name-pass check variable
$isWrongUserPass = false;

if( !isset( $_SESSION['signedIn'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['signedIn'] = false;
}

// If the user clicked "sign out", 
if( isset( $_GET['signout'] ) ) {
    $_SESSION['signedIn'] = false;

    // Change the location to where you want to redirect the user after signing out
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// If the user submitted a name
if ( sha1( $_POST['username'] ) == $username && sha1($_POST['password'] ) == $password){
    $_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
}else{
    $isWrongUserPass = true;
}

if( !$_SESSION['signedIn']):

?>
```

HTML Code:

```
            <?php if( $isWrongUserPass ) { ?>
            <div class="error">Pogresno ste uneli ime ili lozinku!</div>
        <?php } ?>

        <form id="signIn" method="post">
            <label for="username">Ime</label>
            <input style="border-radius: 100px" type="text" id="username" name="username" />
            <label for="password">Lozinka</label>
            <input style="border-radius: 100px" type="password" id="password" name="password" />
            <input style="border-radius: 100px" type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Uloguj Se" />
        </form>
```

This works, but or variables to be printed immediately.I want to be printed after an error in the password or name.Both codes are in one file.

Comment: already changed

Comment: SHA1 is not suitable for password hashing. You should use `password_hash()`.

Comment: check if isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password']){//YOUR PASSWORD CHECK}

Comment: when you go to your webpage first time before submitting username and password, you are checking the password and username, but it is not set.. so iswronguserpass becomes false, before submitting the username and password...

Comment: `if ( sha1( $_POST['username'] ) == $username && sha1($_POST['password'] ) == $password){
`  from where `$username` and `$password` coming from?

Comment: password and $ username is above you on this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't understand my comment,change your password checking like this

```
if(isset($_POST['username'],$_POST['password'])){
   if ( sha1( $_POST['username'] ) == $username && sha1($_POST['password'] ) == $password){
     $_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
   }else{
       $isWrongUserPass = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first you sent `$isWrongUserPass = false;`

and again you set $isWrongUserPass = true in else condition;

remove else condition. will work fine.

```
if ( sha1( $_POST['username'] ) == $username && sha1($_POST['password'] ) == $password){
$_SESSION['signedIn'] = true;
```

}